# Using BeautifulSoup in order to find all "ul" and "li" elements

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-lists

I'm currently working on a crawling-script in Python where I want to map the following HTML-response into a multilist or a dictionary (it does not matter).

My current code is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

req     = Request("https://my.site.com/crawl", headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req)
soup    = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser')
ul      = soup.find('ul', {'class': ''})
```

After running this I get the following result stored in ***ul***:

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="reference" href="#ref1">Data1</a></li>
    <li><a class="reference" href="#ref2">Data2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="reference" href="#ref3">Data3</a></li>
            <li><a class="reference" href="#ref4">Data4</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="reference" href="#ref5"><span class="pre">Data5</span></a></li>
                    <li><a class="reference" href="#ref6"><span class="pre">Data6</span></a></li>
                    .
                    .
                    .
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="reference" href="#ref7">Data7</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="reference" href="#ref8"><span class="pre">Data8</span></a></li>
            <li><a class="reference" href="#ref9"><span class="pre">Data9</span></a></li>
            .
            .
            .
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="reference" href="#ref10">Data10</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="reference" href="#ref11"><span class="pre">Data11</span></a></li>
            <li><a class="reference" href="#ref12">Data12</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

As this is an external site I cannot control the id or class of the elements in the list.

It seems that I can not get my head around this, is there a simple way to arrange the data into a list or dict?:

```
dict = {'Data1': {'href': 'ref1'}, 
        'Data2': {'href': 'ref2', {
                  'Data3': {'href': 'ref3'}, 
                  'Data4': {'href': 'ref4', {
                            'Data5': {'href': 'ref5'},
                            'Data6': {'href': 'ref6'},
                                    .
                                    .
                                    .                }
                                    }
                       }
               }
       }
```

I do feel like this is a cumbersome process, however I do not see any other way of doing it.

Any help to get me going in the right direction is much appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: Your HTML structure is inconsistent, you are missing at least one opening `<li>` (or have a closing `</li>` too many). Do make sure it is HTML clean. In a dictionary, you do need a key for the tested dictionary value. Perhaps `'children'`?

Comment: They are real values that I want to look up in the furure, e.g. `forms` `email` `model`.

Comment: This isn't a valid data structure. In each set of braces, your `href` dicts have keys, but your children dict does not. That isn't a dict, and it isn't a set, it's just a SyntaxError. Maybe you want something like `'href': 'ref2', children: { …`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yeah, you are right about the HTML structure. The data that I recieve is a lot more and I tried to shortened it down. I guess there was added two extra `<li>`-elements by mistake, this is fixed in the post now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just recurse the `ul` element, pulling out the text of all the `li` elements that have text, recursing deeper if there is a `<ul>` element instead:

```
def parse_ul(elem):
    result = {}
    for sub in elem.find_all('li', recursive=False):
        if sub.a is None:
            continue
        data = {k: v for k, v in sub.a.attrs.items() if k != 'class'}
        if sub.ul is not None:
            # recurse down
            data['children'] = parse_ul(sub.ul)
        result[sub.a.get_text(strip=True)] = data
    return result
```

This takes all direct `li` elements; if there is an `<a>` element the text of that anchor element is turned into a key and we store a copy of the tag attributes as the value (ignoring any `class` attributes). If there is *also* a `<ul>` element next to the `a` tag, it is parsed recursively and added as a `children` key to the attribute dictionary for the `<a>` tag.

For your sample input, this produces:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint    
>>> pprint(parse_ul(soup.ul))
{'Data1': {'href': '#ref1'},
 'Data10': {'children': {'Data11': {'href': '#ref11'},
                         'Data12': {'href': '#ref12'}},
            'href': '#ref10'},
 'Data2': {'children': {'Data3': {'href': '#ref3'},
                        'Data4': {'children': {'Data5': {'href': '#ref5'},
                                               'Data6': {'href': '#ref6'}},
                                  'href': '#ref4'}},
           'href': '#ref2'},
 'Data7': {'children': {'Data8': {'href': '#ref8'}, 'Data9': {'href': '#ref9'}},
           'href': '#ref7'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no *trivial* way to do this, but it's not all that cumbersome.

For example, you can do it recursively, something like this:

```
def make_data(ul):
    d = {}
    for a in ul.find_all('a'):
        d[a.text] = {'href': a.attrs['href']}
    lis = ul.find_all('li', recursive=False)
    children = {}
    for li in lis:
        child = li.ul
        if child:
            children[li.a.attrs['href']] = make_data(child)
    if children:
        d['children'] = children
    return d
```

(I had to give each of those `children` dicts a key, because the structure you actually wanted isn't a valid dict.)

Of course you'll want to, e.g., add some error handling, but this should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thank you for helping me along the way, unfortunately it ended up in adding the children multiple times

Answer (score 0):

I really like the Martijn Pieters parse_ul(), but I have some code that do not follow the rules for this parser, with a double `<ul></ul>` inside a single `<li> .. </li>` where the last section got a `<a ... > text </a>` prefixed.
Eg `<li><a ...> <ul> </ul> <a..></a><ul> </ul> </li>`

See below

```
<ul>
  <li><a class="ref" href="#ref1">Data1</a></li>
  <li><a class="ref" href="#ref2">Data2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="ref" href="#ref4">Data4</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a class="ref" href="#ref5"><span class="pre">Data5</span></a>/li>
          <li><a class="ref" href="#ref6"><span class="pre">Data6</span></a></li>
           .
           .
        </ul>
   <!-- a-tag without preceding <li> tag  -->
        <a class="ref" href="#ref4a">Data4a</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a class="ref" href="#ref5a"><span class="pre">Data5a</span></a></li>
          <li><a class="ref" href="#ref6a"><span class="pre">Data6a</span></a></li>
           .
           .
        </ul>               
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
   .
   .
</ul>
```

I can not figure out how to change the parse_ul() so that it accept this deviation and output this ?

```
{'Data1': {'href': '#ref1'},
 'Data2': {'children': {'Data4': {'children': {'Data5': {'href': '#ref5'},
                                               'Data6': {'href': '#ref6'}}},
                                 'href': '#ref4'},
                       {'Data4a': {'children':{'Data5a': {'href': '#ref5a'},
                                               'Data6a': {'href': '#ref6a'}}},
                                 'href': '#ref4a'},
           'href': '#ref2'}
}
```

The following script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pprint

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)     # Init pritty print (pprint)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_contents, 'lxml')
menu_dict = parse_ul(soup.ul)
pp.pprint(menu_dict)
```

will generate the following output, which is missing the second part contained in `<a..></a><ul> </ul>`:

```
{'Data1': {'href': '#ref1'},
 'Data2': {'children': {'Data4': {'children': {'Data5': {'href': '#ref5'},
                                               'Data6': {'href': '#ref6'}}},
                                 'href': '#ref4'},
           'href': '#ref2'}
}
```