# Using BeautifulSoup in order to find all “ul” and “li” elements with minor deviation

Tags: python, html, list, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

In a crawler-script in python I'm using BeautifulSoup to parse a html multi list almost similair to the  question {[Using BeautifulSoup in order to find all "ul" and "li" elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50338108/using-beautifulsoup-in-order-to-find-all-ul-and-li-elements/61963812#61963812)} and answered by Martijn Pieters using his python function parse_ul().

```
def parse_ul(elem):
result = {}
for sub in elem.find_all('li', recursive=False):
    if sub.a is None:
        continue
    data = {k: v for k, v in sub.a.attrs.items() if k != 'class'}
    if sub.ul is not None:
        # recurse down
        data['children'] = parse_ul(sub.ul)
    result[sub.a.get_text(strip=True)] = data
return result
```

I need to parse a multilist that does not follow the rules for Martijn Pieters parser. 
This html multilist contains a double `<ul></ul>` inside a single `<li> .. </li>` where the last section got a `<a ... > text </a>` prefixed (without `<li>`)

Eg `<li><a ...></a><ul> </ul> <a..></a><ul> </ul> </li>`

See below

```
<ul>
  <li><a class="ref" href="#ref1">Data1</a></li>
  <li><a class="ref" href="#ref2">Data2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="ref" href="#ref4">Data4</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a class="ref" href="#ref5"><span class="pre">Data5</span></a>/li>
          <li><a class="ref" href="#ref6"><span class="pre">Data6</span></a></li>
           .
           .
        </ul>
   <!-- a-tag without preceding <li> tag  -->
        <a class="ref" href="#ref4a">Data4a</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a class="ref" href="#ref5a"><span class="pre">Data5a</span></a></li>
          <li><a class="ref" href="#ref6a"><span class="pre">Data6a</span></a></li>
           .
           .
        </ul>               
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
   .
   .
</ul>
```

I can not figure out how to change the parse_ul() so that it accept this deviation and output this ?
Martijn Pieters parser is brilliant and there must also be a brilliant solution for my problem :-)

```
{'Data1': {'href': '#ref1'},
 'Data2': {'children': {'Data4': {'children': {'Data5': {'href': '#ref5'},
                                               'Data6': {'href': '#ref6'}}},
                                 'href': '#ref4'},
                       {'Data4a': {'children':{'Data5a': {'href': '#ref5a'},
                                               'Data6a': {'href': '#ref6a'}}},
                                 'href': '#ref4a'},
           'href': '#ref2'}
}
```

The following script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pprint

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)     # Init pritty print (pprint)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_contents, 'lxml')
menu_dict = parse_ul(soup.ul)
pp.pprint(menu_dict)
```

will generate the following output, which is missing the second part contained in `<a..></a><ul> </ul>`:

```
{'Data1': {'href': '#ref1'},
 'Data2': {'children': {'Data4': {'children': {'Data5': {'href': '#ref5'},
                                               'Data6': {'href': '#ref6'}}},
                                 'href': '#ref4'},
           'href': '#ref2'}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to modify the HTML code before parsing.

This will find all `<a>` tags with previous siblings `<ul>` and inserts them to appropriate positions:

```
txt = '''<ul>
  <li><a class="ref" href="#ref1">Data1</a></li>
  <li><a class="ref" href="#ref2">Data2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="ref" href="#ref4">Data4</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a class="ref" href="#ref5"><span class="pre">Data5</span></a>/li>
          <li><a class="ref" href="#ref6"><span class="pre">Data6</span></a></li>
        </ul>

        <!-- a-tag without preceding <li> tag  -->
        <a class="ref" href="#ref4a">Data4a</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a class="ref" href="#ref5a"><span class="pre">Data5a</span></a></li>
          <li><a class="ref" href="#ref6a"><span class="pre">Data6a</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

# find "lone" <A>+<UL> tags, wrap them in new <LI> tag and append the li tag after parent <LI>:
for a in soup.select('a'):
    prev = a.find_previous_sibling()
    if prev and prev.name == 'ul':
        parent_li = a.parent
        next_ul = a.find_next('ul')

        new_li = soup.new_tag("li")
        new_li.append(a)
        new_li.append(next_ul)

        parent_li.insert_after(new_li)


# this is unchanged code from your question:
def parse_ul(elem):
    result = {}
    for sub in elem.find_all('li', recursive=False):
        if sub.a is None:
            continue
        data = {k: v for k, v in sub.a.attrs.items() if k != 'class'}
        if sub.ul is not None:
            # recurse down
            data['children'] = parse_ul(sub.ul)
        result[sub.a.get_text(strip=True)] = data
    return result

from pprint import pprint
pprint(parse_ul(soup.ul))
```

Prints:

```
{'Data1': {'href': '#ref1'},
 'Data2': {'children': {'Data4': {'children': {'Data5': {'href': '#ref5'}},
                                  'href': '#ref4'},
                        'Data4a': {'children': {'Data5a': {'href': '#ref5a'},
                                                'Data6a': {'href': '#ref6a'}},
                                   'href': '#ref4a'}},
           'href': '#ref2'}}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej .. I were simply stocked in trying to modify the parser in stead of correcting the problem :-)