# Can't get info of a lxml site with Request and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to make a testing project that scraps info of a specific site but with no success.
I followed some tutorials i have found and even an post on stackoverflow. **After all this I'm stuck!**
**help me stepbrothers**, I'm a hot new programmer with python and I can't stop my projects.

more info: this is a lottery website that I was trying to scrap and make some analisys to get a lucky number.

I have followed this tutorials:
https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-collect-data-from-any-website-cb8fad9e9ec5

https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

[Using BeautifulSoup in order to find all "ul" and "li" elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50338108/using-beautifulsoup-in-order-to-find-all-ul-and-li-elements)

All of you have my gratitute!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests 
import html5lib
#import urllib3 # another attemp to make  another req in the url ------failed

url = '''https://loterias.caixa.gov.br/Paginas/Mega-Sena.aspx'''

#another try to take results in the <ul> but I have no qualified results  == None
def parse_ul(elem):#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50338108/using-beautifulsoup-in-order-to-find-all-ul-and-li-elements
    result = {}
    for sub in elem.find_all('li', recursive=False):
        if sub.li is None:
            continue
        data = {k: v for k, v in sub.attrs.items()}
        if sub.ul is not None:
            # recurse down
            data['children'] = parse_ul(sub.ul)
        result[sub.li.get_text(strip=True)] = data
    return result

page = requests.get(url)#taking info from website

print(page.encoding)# == UTF-8

soup = bs(page.content,features="lxml")#takes all info from the url and organizes it ==Beaultiful soup

numbers = soup.find(id='ulDezenas')#searcher in the content of this specific id// another try: soup.find('ul', {'class': ''})

result =  parse_ul(soup)#try to parse info, but none is found EVEN WITH THE ORIGINAL ONE

print(numbers)#The result is below:
'''<ul class="numbers megasena" id="ulDezenas">
<li ng-repeat="dezena in resultado.listaDezenas ">{{dezena.length &gt; 2 ? dezena.slice(1) : dezena}}</li>
</ul>'''
print(result)# == "{}" nothing found

#with open('''D:\Documents\python\_abretesesame.txt''', 'wb') as fd:
#    for chunk in page.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
#        fd.write(chunk)
# =======printing document(HTML) in file still no success in getting the numbers
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main issue is that the content is provided dynamically by `JavaScript` but you can get the information via another url:

```
jsonData = requests.get('https://servicebus2.caixa.gov.br/portaldeloterias/api/megasena/').json()
```

will give you folowing `JSON`:

```
{'tipoJogo': 'MEGA_SENA', 'numero': 2468, 'nomeMunicipioUFSorteio': 'SÃO PAULO, SP', 'dataApuracao': '02/04/2022', 'valorArrecadado': 158184963.0, 'valorEstimadoProximoConcurso': 3000000.0, 'valorAcumuladoProximoConcurso': 0.0, 'valorAcumuladoConcursoEspecial': 36771176.89, 'valorAcumuladoConcurso_0_5': 33463457.98, 'acumulado': False, 'indicadorConcursoEspecial': 1, 'dezenasSorteadasOrdemSorteio': ['022', '041', '053', '042', '035', '057'], 'listaResultadoEquipeEsportiva': None, 'numeroJogo': 2, 'nomeTimeCoracaoMesSorte': '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', 'tipoPublicacao': 3, 'observacao': '', 'localSorteio': 'ESPAÇO DA SORTE', 'dataProximoConcurso': '06/04/2022', 'numeroConcursoAnterior': 2467, 'numeroConcursoProximo': 2469, 'valorTotalPremioFaixaUm': 0.0, 'numeroConcursoFinal_0_5': 2470, 'listaDezenas': ['022', '035', '041', '042', '053', '057'], 'listaDezenasSegundoSorteio': None, 'listaMunicipioUFGanhadores': [{'posicao': 1, 'ganhadores': 1, 'municipio': 'SANTOS', 'uf': 'SP', 'nomeFatansiaUL': '', 'serie': ''}], 'listaRateioPremio': [{'faixa': 1, 'numeroDeGanhadores': 1, 'valorPremio': 122627171.8, 'descricaoFaixa': '6 acertos'}, {'faixa': 2, 'numeroDeGanhadores': 267, 'valorPremio': 34158.18, 'descricaoFaixa': '5 acertos'}, {'faixa': 3, 'numeroDeGanhadores': 20734, 'valorPremio': 628.38, 'descricaoFaixa': '4 acertos'}], 'id': None, 'ultimoConcurso': True, 'exibirDetalhamentoPorCidade': True, 'premiacaoContingencia': None}
```

Simply extract `dezenasSorteadasOrdemSorteio` and prozess in `list comprehension`:

```
[n if len(n) < 2 else n[1:] for n in jsonData['listaDezenas']]
```

Result will be:

```
['22', '35', '41', '42', '53', '57']
```

##### Example

```
import requests

jsonData = requests.get('https://servicebus2.caixa.gov.br/portaldeloterias/api/megasena/').json()
print([n if len(n) < 2 else n[1:] for n in jsonData['listaDezenas']])
```